# How to convert specific format array into hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array:

```
ar = ["p=abhZRAh7Un", "a=2", "c=1", "l=3033102", "r=1", "rt=mr", "pid=136330865", "pdid=AiOIhH2vzMPqvhYkxXOxeA%3D%3D", "lks=54.0311", "fks=54.0311"]
```

and need to convert it into a hash with keys `p`, `a`, `c`, etc. and values – whatever is to the right of the equal sign. What is an elegant way to do that in ruby?

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Hash[ar.map{|s| s.split("=")}]
```

Comment: That's hot. nice solution

Comment: be warned though: if your values may contain a '=' character, the `split` will not only split the string into key-value, but will split the value also! Unless you are aware of it and actually want that behaviour, you **should add a LIMIT** to the `split`.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'cgi'
ar = ["p=abhZRAh7Un", "a=2", "c=1", "l=3033102", "r=1", "rt=mr", "pid=136330865", "pdid=AiOIhH2vzMPqvhYkxXOxeA%3D%3D", "lks=54.0311", "fks=54.0311"]
CGI.parse(ar.join('&'))
```

outputs:

```
=> {"rt"=>["mr"], "fks"=>["54.0311"], "pid"=>["136330865"], "lks"=>["54.0311"], "pdid"=>["AiOIhH2vzMPqvhYkxXOxeA=="], "r"=>["1"], "l"=>["3033102"], "c"=>["1"], "a"=>["2"], "p"=>["abhZRAh7Un"]}
```

Comment: thank you, but I don't need each value to be an array. It should be a string. How to do that? I don't understand what exactly CGI.parse(ar.join('&')) does.

Comment: It's taking a URL querystring (in the URL for a GET you might see `field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3...`. and parsing it out as a hash. I thought it would be clever, but now I'm trying to get those arrays out of there.

Comment: Actually, that might work for me as well. I know there will be just one element in this array, so it's OK. Thank you.

Comment: sawa's answer is better anyway. I have no idea why ruby decided to give me a hash of arrays. php's `parse_str` gives me a straight-up hash of values.